# Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB > BC$ and $\gamma$ its circumscribed circle. Let $M, N$ be on the sides $[AB]$, $[BC]$, so that $AM = CN$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB > BC$ and $\gamma$ its circumscribed circle. Let $M, N$ be on the sides $[AB]$, $[BC]$ respectively, so that $AM = CN$. If $K = MN \cap AC$, $P$ is the center of the circle inscribed in the triangle $AMK$, $Q$ is the center of the circle $K$−exscribed of the triangle $CNK$ (opposite the vertex $K$,tangent to $CN$). If $R$ is the midpoint of the arc $ABC$ of $\gamma$, show that $RP = RQ$.

[image]

I've tried constructing some random points (like the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $QP$ with $\gamma$) to notice any properties, but that did not help. I've also tried redefining the point $R$.

Comment: Where does this exercise come from ?

Comment: Found it in a preparation material for my country's MO.

Comment: I am asking this question because you have not included trigonometry-tag in your post. Do you accept an answer which uses trigonometry or are you looking for pure synthetic proofs only?

Comment: This question got an upvote from me, it is the quality of the NMO problem in the first place that must be honored. In the question, it would be nice to insert further details of the problem, e.g. the country explicitly, the year (and day), possibly the author if known. The information that we have an NMO problem is so important, it must be part of the provided context (not only a comment). Such informations make the problem searchable. Note that this searching possibility is a main trump of other sites (like AoPS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be also a picture proof, the reader may want to ignore below everything but the pictures and come with her or his own proof. But for didactic purposes, since we have a NMO problem and want to collect all points, there is also the story around the pics.

---

I need a lemma first, some points from the posted question are involved, notations are kept. I will introduce some more points, showing how the picture was realized.

> Given is a triangle $\Delta ABC$, we draw its circumcenter $\odot(ABC)=\odot(O)$ with center $O$, the diameter perpendicular on $AC$ is $RS$, with $R$ on the same side of $AC$ as $B$. Consider on $AC$ points $M_1$, $N_1$
> on $AC$, reflected w.r.t. the side bisector $RS$ of $AC$, denote by $m$ the common length $m=AM_1=CN_1$. Circles centered in $A$, respectively $C$ with radius $m$ further intersect the segments $AB$ in $M$, and respectively $CB$ in $N$. Let $\Omega$ be the circumcenter of the cirumcircle $\odot(BMN)$ of $\Delta BMN$.
>
> **Then**:
>
> - $R$ is also on the circle $\odot(\Omega)=\odot(BMN)$,
> - $RM=RN$.

[image: Some NMO olympiad problem involving equal segments on the sides of a triangle]

*Proof:* Draw parallels and perpendiculars through the circumcenters $O$ and $\Omega$ to the sides $BA$ and $BC$ of $\Delta ABC$. We obtain as in the picture two orange triangles with same hypotenuse $O\Omega$, and one of the legs is $m/2$ in each, the distance from the mid points of $AB$ and $MB$ for one triangle, respectively mid points of $CB$ and $NB$ for the other one.
These triangles are thus congruent, so $\Omega O$ is an angle bisector for an angle delimited by sides parallel to $BA$ and $BC$. So
$\Omega O$ is parallel to the angle bisector $BS$ of $\widehat{ABC}$. Since $\Omega O\|BS\perp BR$ we obtain that $\Omega O$ is also the side bisector of $BR$, thus $\Omega B=\Omega R$, so $R$ is also on the circle $\odot(\Omega)=\odot(BMN)$.

To see that $RM=RN$, compare $\Delta RNC$ and $\Delta RMA$. They have $RC=RA$, $NC=m=NA$, and $\widehat{NCR}=\widehat{BCR}=\widehat{BAR}=\widehat{MAR}$. So the two triangles are congruent. (And a rotation around $R$ with angle $\widehat{NRM}=\widehat{NBM}=\widehat{CBA}=\hat B$ brings one triangle into the other.)

$\square$

---

We are now in position to show the claimed result. Here there is a slightly changed way to introduce points, done in an equivalent manner. Since some other points, useful for the proof, are also introduced let us explicitly restate:

> **Problem:** Let $\Delta ABC$ be given, consider $M,N,R,S$ as in the previous *Lemma*. Let $K=AC\cap MN$. Then $\bbox[yellow]{(1)}$ the quadrilaterals $AMRK$ and $CNRK$ are cyclic. Let $P^*$, $Q^*$ be the mid points of the arcs $\overset\frown{AM}$ of $\odot(AMRK)$, and respectively $\overset\frown{CN}$ of
> $\odot(CNRK)$, that can be defined alternatively as the intersections of the angle bisector
> $$\kappa$$
> of $\widehat{AKM}=\widehat{CKN}$ with the two mentioned circles. Draw the interior and exterior angle bisectors of $\Delta ABC$ going either through $I$, its incenter, or through $I_B$, its $B$-excenter. Consider the intersections of these bisectors with $\kappa$:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> P'&=\kappa\cap IA  \ , & Q'&=\kappa\cap IC\ ,\\
> P &=\kappa\cap I_BA\ , & Q &=\kappa\cap I_BC\ .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Then $\bbox[yellow]{(2)}$
> $\odot(APMP')$ is a circle centered in $P^*$, and
> $\odot(CQNQ')$ is a circle centered in $Q^*$.
>
> In particular we have $\bbox[yellow]{(3)}$:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> RA&=RC\ ,\\
> RM&=RN\ ,\\
> RP^*&=RQ^*\ ,\\
> RP&=RQ\ ,\\
> RP'&=RQ'\ .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

[image: NMO restatement of problem]

**Proof:** For $\bbox[yellow]{(1)}$ - using the above Lemma:
$$
\widehat{RNK} =
\widehat{RNM} =
\widehat{RBM} =
\widehat{RBA} =
\widehat{RCA} \ .
$$
So $CNRK$ cyclic. Similarly $AMRK$ cyclic.

$\bbox[yellow]{(2)}$ take first from the picture only the piece involving the points
$K,C,N;Q,Q',Q*$ and the angle bisectors in $C,K$. Denote by $x,y$ half of the angle $\hat C$, respectively $\hat K$ in $\Delta CKN$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{Q^*CQ'}
&=
\widehat{Q^*CN}
  +
\widehat{NCQ'}
=
\widehat{Q^*KN}
  +
\widehat{NCQ'}
=x+y=\widehat{Q'CK}
  +
\widehat{Q'KC}
\\
&=\widehat{Q^*Q'C}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $\Delta Q^*Q'C$ isosceles, $Q^*Q'=Q^*C$. The angle bisectors $CQ$, $CQ'$ are perpendicular, so $\Delta QCQ'$ has a right angle in $C$. Its mid point of the hypotenuse is the only point of this side at same distance from $C$ and $Q'$, so it is $Q^*$. We obtain thus $Q^*Q=Q^*C=Q^*Q'$. Since $Q^*$ is the mid point of the arc $\overset\frown{CN}$ of $\odot(CNRK)$, we can add also $Q^*N$ to the chain of equalities. So $Q^*$ is the center of the circle $\odot(CQNQ')$. The same happens also for $\odot(APMP')$.

We can attack $\bbox[yellow]{(3)}$. The obvious $R$-rotation moves $\Delta RNC\to\Delta RMA$, so take in the movement also corresponding objects, circles $\odot(RNC)\to\odot(RMA)$, arcs of them $\overset\frown{NC}\to\overset\frown{MA}$, and their mid points $Q^*\to P^*$. So
$$
RQ^*=RP^*\ ,
$$
so the perpendicular bisector of $P^*Q^*$ goes through $R$, and w.r.t. this bisector we have reflected pairs of points $(P^*,Q^*)$, and $(P,Q)$, and $(P',Q')$, the last two pairs since we know the distances on the line $\kappa=KPP^*P'QQ^*Q$.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: May be the figure I constructed is a particular case where following points can be seen:

1-M is mid point of AB, O is the center of circle $\gamma$ so $OM\bot AB$.

2- Draw  circle $\alpha$ on diameter PQ, mark it's center as E.

3-Construct isosceles trapezoid ACGM on base AC. Connect O to G and extend it to meet circle $\gamma$ at I.So $OG\bot CG$

4-Draw a tangent from Q, meets circle $\alpha$ at F. You will find $QF||CG$, $EI\bot QF$.

5- Connect F to E, clearly $FE\bot PQ$ and EFQ is isosceles right angled triangle.

6-Draw perpendicular bisector of AC, it intersect circle $\gamma$ at R which is coincident on FE; also R is midpoint of arc ABC.

In this way $RP=RQ$.

In fact the key point is that R is where EF and perpendicular bisector of AC intersect.

I can send you the figure if I have an address.

Comment: Please always make clear in an answer *in the first line(s)* if it is **not a full answer**, and/or if it considers only a **special case** that may be or not an interesting special case. This would be a fair way to organize the information, some potential upvoters may reconsider else their decision *after* having this information, some potential answerers may even not read the question any longer, since it seems to have an answer. Sending pictures via email is not a good idea, this simply ignores the community. And having an address is even worse, since bots can fish it too, if posted.